# Log In to GitLab account without Email Confirmation

Tags: email, gitlab, email-confirmation

I created a **GitLab** account but I accidentally provided an email account that did not exist as the email. I cannot understand how **GitLab** couldn't verify that during the Registration Process. So now I cannot log into my **GitLab** account as it asks me to

> confirm my email before continuing

. I did not provide the email as the *username*, however.

So now I seem to be locked out of my account because of a faulty email address. Is there any way that I could change the email to the correct one? I have the username and password.

Note: the username is important and I don't want it to be changed, so creating another account is out of the question.

[image]